# How to get this/these block(s)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm not sure if this is one or two blocks, but I would like to know if I can get it/them in the Overworld.  I put an image below, but it is the setup that heals the Ender Dragon.

I know the bottom turns to regular bedrock when the crystal thing is destroyed, but is there a way I can get this look in the Overworld?  If so, how?

[image: Healer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Minecraft 1.9, [end crystals](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Crystal) can be crafted using glass, an eye of ender, and a ghast tear and then placed into the overworld.

[image: crafting recipe]

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  It is correct and offers information no other answer has provided.

Comment: @Batophobia I suspect that the reason is that someone is serially downvoting me.

Answer (score 9):

You **cannot** get those blocks in the Overworld *without mods*. [The Ender Crystal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Crystal) is an *entity* and, for that reason, cannot be collected. It also cannot be crafted.

There are some mods that let you place entities as you wish, at least on the server-side.

Comment: that isnt true... there is a spawn egg for that "block" (i dont know what the ID for the spawn egg is, but there is one)

Comment: @RustyMembers There is an egg for it, but it does not spawn it.

Comment: in one of the early versions it work, but i guess they "fixed" it

Answer (score 5):

This is called an Ender Crystal. It is not a block but an entity and can be spawned in using

```
/summon EnderCrystal
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [single player commands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-162-single-player-commands-v49-official-download-spc-noclip/). It's a command mod that is very useful for the ability to spawn entities and other uses.

There is an automatic installer that back-ups your minecraft.jar and worlds in case you change you mind.

Answer (score -2):

The **endercrystal** can be spawned, although not in item form. If it was a block it would be 1 unit or smaller.

If you want to spawn this in, type the command `/summon EnderCrystal` in chat.

All entities have these properties:

- A position, velocity, and rotation (as according to ordinary Newtonian physics).
- A specific volume they occupy, which is a 3-dimensional box with a fixed height and width (square when viewed from the top, and not rotating).
- Current health.
- Whether they are on fire. Fire reduces health gradually and displays flames covering the entity.
- Effects, caused mainly by splash potions. Spiders can also spawn with effects when playing on hard mode.

[Source: Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Entity)

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: Probably because this has already been said in another answer, and this adds nothing except pasting in a bunch of irrelevant information about entities. (Irrelevant info is usually understood as a sign that the writer doesn't actually know what the answer is, since they can't tell what's important to copy and what isn't.)